# SQL PIVOT a table with no column names

Tags: sql, pivot, unpivot

I had a query returning value in a list.
eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE name IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5', 'name6', 'name7', 'name8', 'name9', 'name10')
```

I want to see what might not be in the list.
eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM #list
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM some_table)
```

My list has a few hundred values.
How can I turn my list into a table?

```
SELECT 'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5', 'name6', 'name7', 'name8', 'name9', 'name10'
```

INTO #list
    UNPIVOT(?????)

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean by 'list'. The first query returns a table, the second query looks valid, then the 3rd is returning one record with lots of columns. What is actually happening?

Comment: Is your first query the actual query from which you want to exclude some results?  You can do that with `WHERE` or `EXCEPT`.  I think we need more information.

Comment: Basicly I want to find the names that are not in the table. So if 'name129' is not in some_table I wan't to be to return it from a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table SomeTable (  -- The reference table
    Name varchar(20));

insert SomeTable(Name)
values
     ('name1')
    ,('name2')
    ,('name3')
    ,('name4')
    ,('name5');


select T1.Name from
(values                 -- The list to compare to the reference table
     ('name1')
    ,('name2')
    ,('name129')) as T1(Name)
EXCEPT
select Name from SomeTable;
```

This will return "name129" since that value is in the list but not in the reference table.  The same effect can be achieved with `NOT EXISTS` or with an outer join.

```
select T1.Name from
(values                 -- The list to compare to the reference table
     ('name1')
    ,('name2')
    ,('name129')) as T1(Name)
left outer join SomeTable as st
    on st.Name = T1.Name
where st.Name is NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing something similar to this. I was trying to do it without having to change each item in my list because I didn't want to have to spend an hour going through and adding the brackets to each item in the list. In the end I downloaded and used a different text editor (sublime) to formate the list and then ran code like this.

Comment: You can use SQL as a SQL generator -- `select '('''+st.Name+'''),' from SomeTable as st`.  Copy the ouput into your code editor of choice.  Then there's only a little bit of tweaking around the beginning and end of the statement.